# editing views in IB that start off the screen

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, interface-builder

I have some views that start off the screen and then slide in and out at various times. In IB, the x,y positions are off the screen, because that is where I want them to start.

Now, I could just put them anywhere in the x,y space in IB and have the viewController's viewDidLoad method move them off the screen initially.

My question is, since they are currently off the screen in IB, is there an easy way to access and edit them in IB without changing the x,y position of a view first so that it appears on the screen in IB? Because I am editing these views fairly often.

If there isn't, then I'll probably just position them anywhere in the visible space in IB and add some stuff to viewDidLoad to get them out of the way. Or any other suggestions I'd love to hear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a separate view, just drag it to where you want it, and double click it's name in the objects list as seen in edo42's answer. You could also figure out the final x/y coordinates and set those with your code, and just move the view wherever is convinient.

Answer (score 0):

You click there

[image]

and then select your view here

[image]

Comment: I can select my view fine, it's how to edit it when it is off the screen, or in other words, since it is not on the visible drawing space of the device IB, it doesn't appear in IB for me to add buttons, etc to it, unless I change its x,y position to bring it onto the visible space.

Comment: only way to do this is to put it out of the main view, link it with an IBOutlet and load it programmatically by doing in the responsible controller `[self.view addSubview:myOffscreenView];`.

Comment: or to do what XenElement says